# In Mogoose i found my document with find, but using update not

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using nodejs and mongo (with mongooose) to build a simple aplication, but i have this little problem.

If i search my documento using a find method, i found the document (and yes, i can update in this), but if i use a update method, o cant find it. Why?

My controller method

```
var query = {
        _id: ObjectId(req.params.runner_id)
    };

    Runner.find(query, function(e,o) {
        console.log(o); //here i found
    })

    Runner.update(query, req.body, function (err, qtd) {
        console.log(qtd); //here note

        if (err) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    })
```

My Schema

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Runner", new Schema({
    cellphone: {
        type: String,
        require: "qual o telefone?",
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function (v) {
                var re = /^\d{11}$/;
                return (v == null || v.trim().length < 1) || re.test(v);
            },
            message: "telefone inválido"
        }
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    advisors: [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            require: "entre com o nome"
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            require: "entre com o e-mail"
        },
        advisor: {
            type: ObjectId,
            require: "qual a assessoria?"
        }
    }]
}));
```

My output

with update -> { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
with find -> [ { _id: 5a0b99a9328fec0e4111ca52,
    cellphone: '85999981114',
    __v: 0,
    advisors: [ [Object] ],
    created_at: Wed Nov 15 2017 01:34:33 GMT+0000 (UTC) } ]

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   var query = {
        _id: ObjectId(req.params.id)
    };

    Runner.find(query, function(e,o) {
        console.log(o); //here i found
    })
}
app.put('/:id', function(req, res){
    var Id=req.params.id;
 Runner.findById(Id, function (err, qtd) {
        console.log(qtd); //here qtd will found

        if (err) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
}
```